# Some of the IP-addresses are not getting pinged in my network

Tags: java, networking

I am using this code to get all of the IP-addresses in my network and name of their respective Computers/Systems.

```
byte[] ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getAddress(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) 
    { 
    ip[3] = (byte)i; 
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip); 
    if (address.isReachable(1000)) 
    { 
        System.out.println(address.getHostAddress()+"can b pinged" +"with Name"+ InetAddress.getByAddress(ip).getHostName() );
    }
```

According to my results some of the systems in y network shows their ping status but some of them gets missed. What can be the problem ?

Comment: Did you read `isReachable`'s documentation?

Comment: nope will you suggest me to read that ?

Comment: The isReachable() method works by trying to connect to TCP port 7. It doens't actually care whether port 7 is closed or not. All it cares about is whether there is a response of any kind to the connect. A ConnectException rates as isReachable = true, and it should take about the same amount of time as a successful connection, maybe even quicker. A connect timeout, host not reachable, etc, rate as false @UsagiMiyamoto